# Help with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, string

I have a string of the form: "CCCyyyyyyBBBCCCxxxxxCCCyyyyyCCCzzzzz1CCCrrrrrr"

I need to get some substring after BBB that starts with CCC and ends with 1 (includes CCC only one time). What regular expression I can write for that?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free code machine.

Comment: What kind of regex-dialect is "Urgent"?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how to "tell" the regex to start finding from BBB but not to include BBB. Another thing that I can't figure is how to tell it to include CCC just one time.

Comment: You really need to tell us which regex engine you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/BBB.*(CCC.*1)/
```

- Start with BBB.
- Then something before CCC appears.
- Then anything that is *not* CCC (so that it does not appear more than once in the substring).
- Then a 1.
- The substring is between `(` and `)` so that you can parse it out.

Comment: Is that really working? I think not. With greedy matching your .* should contain a lot of CCCs as well.

Comment: @pvblivs: In JavaScript, `"CCCyyyyyyBBBCCCxxxxxCCCyyyyyCCCzzzzz1CCCrrrrrr".match(/BBB.*(CCC(?!CCC).*1)/)` results in `CCCzzzzz1` which I believe is what the OP wants. Just to make sure, the `(?!CCC)` prevents any `CCC` from appearing in the `.*`.

Comment: I came up with this: /BBB.*(CCC.*(^CCC)*1).*/; basically the same thing though. I tested it with JS too lol.

Comment: Wouldn't that match a single occurrence of [^C]? I thought bracket notation was strictly single character..

Comment: Hmm, ok, I got to play around with it again a bit, I think :-)

Comment: @pimvdb, you are doing it wrong, but it works because the first `.*` is greedy, and the expression backtracks till the last `CCC` is found. Your lookahead does nothing, and does not prevent the second `.*` from containing `CCC` (only prevents it from starting with `CCC`). If you want some string that does not contain `CCC` you can use `(?:(?!CCC).)*` or `(?:[^C]+|C(?!CC))*`.

Comment: @Qtax: 'and the expression backtracks till the last CCC is found' - in that case it should stop at the last CCC before rrrrrr which is not the case. I'm not able to create an input that fails - could you please show me one?

Comment: This is wrong. Your lookahead is only applied right after the starting `CCC`.

Comment: @pimvdb, I didn't say that it would fail, I said that you are doing it wrong and that the lookahead is useless. Remove the lookahead and it will be equivalent still.

Comment: @pimvdb I think this will not work: `CCCyyyyyyBBBCCCxxxxxCCCyyyyyCCCzzzzz1zzzz1CCCrrrrrr`

Comment: @Karolis: It ends with the last 1, which is not explicitly wrong according to the OP's question.

Comment: But it fails if there is more than one `CCC...1` sequence in the string (it finds only the last one). And the `(?!CCC)` lookahead is still meaningless.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: The OP states 'I need to get some substring' so one is enough. I agree about the lookahead though.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=BBB.*)CCC(?:(?!CCC).)*1
```

will work with the .NET regex engine, for example (it uses indefinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions).

```
(?<=BBB.*)  # Assert that there is a "BBB" somewhere before in the string
CCC         # Match CCC
(?:         # Match...
 (?!CCC)    # ...unless the next character is at the start of another "CCC"...
 .          # any character
)*          # Do this any number of times
1           # Match a "1"
```

If your regex engine can't handle the lookbehind assertion, use

```
BBB.*?(CCC(?:(?!CCC).)*1)
```

and use group 1 as the match result.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one possible match in the string, a simple way to do it would be:

```
BBB.*(CCC[^1]*1)
```

Because `.*` is greedy `CCC` will match the last occurance of `CCC` (that is followed by `1`), thus there can't be any between the matched `CCC` and `1`.

Comment: Clever. Hopefully not too clever...

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for regular expressions is actually quite good. Did you look into the documentation of `java.util.Pattern`? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

With that you should be able to figure that out yourself and at the same time understand why it works :-)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

not my code - but here is an excellent freeware to test your regepx http://weitz.de/regex-coach/